# Need the Specific Row to be stored into Database after Approve Button Click

Tags: php, mysql

So regarding my dilemma, I have already coded my website to return a list of rescheduled classes into a table for the admin to approve or disapprove of it. This list of rescheduled classes is retrieved from the database.

What I want to find out is, when the Approve button is clicked, the code will store the specific row's data into the database ([let's say I want just the first row's data to be approved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kksRe.jpg)). How do I do that? I want to do this if possible with its primary key but from what I understand, the primary keys aren't stable as for example, if an entry from that list is deleted, the key will not get replaced but rather the auto increment continues.

Here's my code for the table:

```
<div class="dashboard-content__panel " data-panel-id="class_replacement">
    <div class="dashboard-list report-content">
       <div id="report" class="panel panel-primary panel-table table-responsive reportTable" style="border:none; ">
         <div class="panel-body " >
           <table id="report-table" class="table table-hover"  width="100%" >
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Subject Code</th>
                 <th>Subject Rescheduling Date and Subject Start Time</th>
                 <th>Duration (hours)</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                 <th>Select Venue</th>
                 <th>Approve/Disapprove</th>

               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <?php
               $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fyp1web");
               if ($conn -> connect_error) {
                 die("Connection Failed: ". $conn-> connect_error);
               }

               $sql = "SELECT * from class_rescheduling";
               $result = $conn-> query($sql);


               while ($rs = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $rs["newSubjectID"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $rs["newDateTime"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $rs["newDuration"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $rs["newStatus"]; ?></td>
               <td> <select name="classname">
               <?php
               $sql2 = "SELECT className FROM class_rooms";
               $result2 = $conn-> query($sql2);
               while ($rs1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
               ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $rs1['className']; ?>"><?php echo $rs1["className"]; ?></option>
               <?php
               }
               ?>
               </select></td>
               <td><button class='btn' type='submit' name='approve'>Approve</button><button class='btn' type='submit' name='disapprove'>Disapprove</button></td>
               </tr>
             <?php
             }
             ?>
             </tbody>
                 <tfoot>
                 </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Question is not clear?What do you wanna retrieve?Add bit more to your question

Comment: You should revise the code to include the pk when you send the data to the server. Perhaps a hidden input control?

Comment: I have included an image link above to specify my table. Let's say I want to retrieve the first row's data and selected venue when Approve button is clicked to be stored into another database table.

Comment: Why not simply store it in the correct table to begin with, perhaps with an extra column 'approved' which is set to 0 by default